# Angular - Interceptor HTTP return value from promise

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I have to apply a decryption on the body of the return of a request via Interceptor, however the method of decrypting is asynchronous and returns a promise.

Here's an excerpt from the class:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {

return next.handle(req).pipe(map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    let _body;

    this.cryptMethod.decrypt(event.body).this(res => _body = res); // Método assíncrono

    return event.clone({ body: JSON.parse(_body) });

  }
  return event;
}));
}`
```

It turns out that the "this.cryptMethod.decrypt ()" is asynchronous, so the return is reached before the _body is populated.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the promise from `mergeMap` and chain `map` to it. Rather than use `.then` you can use `async` as well:

```
.pipe(mergeMap(async (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    const _body = await this.cryptMethod.decrypt(event.body);
    return event.clone({ body: JSON.parse(_body) });
  }
});
```

You could also do:

```
.pipe(
  mergeMap(async (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      return this.cryptMethod.decrypt(event.body);
    }
  }),
  map(_body => {
    if (_body) {
      return event.clone({ body: JSON.parse(_body) });
    }
  })
);
```

...but it's more verbose and requires two conditional checks.

Comment: Thank you!

The first solution worked!

Thank you so!